# Para um conjunto não ordenado de Listeners qual a melhor implementação java.util.Set a ser usada?

Tags: java, design-pattern, collection

Estou desenvolvendo um `Handle` para um stream de dados, onde serão lançados periodicamente eventos que deverão ser capturado por um pequeno conjunto de `Listeners` de 1 a 5 `listeners`.

Este conjunto de `listeners` não precisam ser acionados em sequência de cadastro, apenas será garantido que caso seja lançado alguma `excpetion`, esta seja disponibilizada no `log`, sem que interrompa os demais.

Qual a melhor implementação da Interface `java.util.Set` considerando:

- Não há necessidade de ordenação
- O conjunto será constante (não será imutável, porém não sofrera constante mudanças durante a execução)
- Não será necessário que em chamadas recorrentes sejam obtidos na mesma ordem
- Não será necessário que sejam Thread Safe.
- O conjunto será pequeno, inicialmente de 1 a 5 `listeners`.

Comment: Precisa ser um `Set`? Para um conjunto tão pequeno, um `ArrayList` + uma checagem de duplicatas deve ser bom o bastante... Qualquer outra implementação de conjunto provavelmente vai ter um *overhead* desnecessário nesse cenário de tão pouca escala. (o que não significa que não possa ser usado, uma vez que a diferença de performance será minúscula - a menos que existam muitos objetos observáveis, cada um com seu conjunto de *listeners* - e a **conveniência** da interface `Set` pode ser interessante; nesse caso eu responderia "qualquer uma")

Comment: Não há necessidade de ser um Set, o List também poderia ser usado, porém  corre-se o risco da duplicata o set me protege e evita deu ter que me preocupar com a checagem sugerida.

Answer (score 2):

Use um [`CopyOnWriteArraySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html). Segundo a documentação, é a implementação ideal pros casos em que os "tamanhos dos conjuntos geralmente se mantém pequenos" e "operações somente-leitura são muito mais frequentes que operações mutantes". Ela também é *thread-safe*, mas apenas operações de escrita possuem um *overhead* associado, a consulta via iteradores é bastante rápida (que é o que você vai usar com mais frequência, i.e. quando um evento ocorrer você vai percorrer os ouvintes notificando-os do mesmo).

Em suma, é basicamente uma implementação da interface `Set` via um `ArrayList`, tal como eu havia [sugerido em comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80079/para-um-conjunto-n%C3%A3o-ordenado-de-listeners-qual-a-melhor-implementa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-java-util#comment162590_80079), e ainda mantendo a conveniência da interface `Set` (mais a estratégia *copy-on-write*, para *thread-safety*). Para conjuntos pequenos e que não mudam com frequência, essa implementação será a melhor que você poderia conseguir, ou ao menos algo muito próximo disso.

Comment: Não se aplica aos requisitos que citei.

Comment: @Delfino Qual deles, e por que?

Comment: Não será necessário que sejam Thread Safe.

Comment: @Delfino "Não ser necessário" é diferente de "ser proibido", não? Na minha resposta eu frisei que a operação mais comum - consulta via iteradores - não traz nenhum *overhead* adicional (pois não implica num *lock*). Eu mantenho minha posição que essa é a implementação mais indicada pro seu caso, mas como de costume, pra ter certeza só testando...